# Mean in pandas without dtype

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, mean

I want to find mean of a df but dont want the dtype object.

Just want the mean figure

say if the df was

```
5
5
4
```

I want 4.66666

Comment: ``df.mean().item()``

Comment: [`df.mean`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mean.html) returns a [`pd.Series`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.html), with one entry for each column. If you first select the column, e.g. `df['column_name'].mean()` you will get a python float.

Comment: @sammywemmy yeah.. thanks!!